# Getting value of previous selected item (dropDown)

Tags: vb.net

When a user changes the selected item on a dropdown I need to get the PREVIOUS item selected,

EX:
dropdown items:

1) Questions

2) Jobs

3) Tags

4) Badges

User has #2 Selected and then changes to #4 -- How can I get the value of #2 when they change the selection?

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance variable in your form (WinForms) or window (WPF).

When a user selects an item:

1. Do what you want to do.
2. Save the current item index in the instance variable.

In step 1, you can now access the instance variable to get the previously selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable that will contain the previous value.

When the user changes the selection in the combobox, set the variable to the currently selected value.  Allow the selection to be changed.  You now will have the previous value.

If you need to have the history of changes, then the global variable would be a collection.  Then on changed event, add the current selection to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If your control is bound to data, there is no need to "Squirrel" the old value away, your data provider usually does this for you.

For example, if you are bound to a DataRow, this code will get the previous value.

```
? = [Your DataRow].item("[Your column name]",OrigialVersion)
```

This varies based on your data but ultimately, you could always re-query the database to get the original value as well.

Regardless of what you are bound too, if you ask the datasource for it's value during the `Validating` event of the control, it will have not changed yet so it will give you the old value, which you can then compare against the current selection.

Lastly, if you are not bound to data, I typically store the old value in the `TAG` property on the `GotFocus` event of the control. Then you can compare against that.

Hope this provides some other options that might help you, depending on your case.